# How would I create a factory that only queries the database once, but can be used by many controllers?

Tags: angularjs

I have a 'messages' factory that will query my database for a list of messages.

I'm using the list of messages in two different places. Once to add a message count indicator, and then once to show a list of messages. Since I'm injecting the service into two different controllers, it seems like it's creating two instances of my factory, and hitting the database twice for the list.

How would I set things up to only ask for the list once, and use the list for both display and count purposes in both controllers?

My factory looks like this:

```
myApp.factory('messagesService', [
    '$rootScope',
    function($rootScope) {
        var messages = [];

        function query() {
            // Would actually hit the database asyncronously
            messages = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
            console.log('query');
            $rootScope.$emit('messages.update');
        }

        function all() {
            return messages;
        }

        return {
            query: query,
            all: all
        }
    }
]);
```

My controllers are using blocks like this to watch for changes:

```
$rootScope.$on('messages.update', function() {
    $scope.messagesCount = messagesService.all().length;
});
```

But it means i need a `messagesService.query();` in each controller for things to be reliable.

So here are a few jsFiddle examples of it as I have things now:

1. Doesn't work (only updates the header): http://jsfiddle.net/TSLfc/1/
2. Works but would break if I didn't load the dashboard controller:
   http://jsfiddle.net/TSLfc/2/
3. Works every time, but queries the server twice:
   http://jsfiddle.net/TSLfc/3/

Is there a better way to organize my code? Should I build out the messages factory into it's own full module?

Comment: Why don't you can the query when the service is instantiated? Of why don't you call it from every controller, but make the query function do nothing if it has already been called once?

Comment: Yes, you could perform the call inside the service, on instantiation. Then you would keep the  returned data inside the service and access it from the different controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here (<kbd>[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4MfmLvoUJ1ld8GUWlSQC?p=preview)</kbd>) is how I would do it:

I have gone back and modified my previous answer, updating with what we discussed in the comments below as well as using promises instead of the `timeout` as an asynchronous simulation I was showing before (see revision history for reference).

I also removed every variable/function that didn't need to be returned to the controller from the service object, if it doesn't need to be accessed via the controller than it doesn't need to be included on the returned object.

```javascript
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('messagesService', [
    '$q',
    '$rootScope',
    '$http',

function ($q, $rootScope, $http) {
    var mService = {};

    mService.messages = [];
    var queryInit = false;

    // We don't need to access this function in the controller
    // So I am not going to attach to the returned object
    var getMessages = function () {
        // Stops each controller from getting messages when loaded
        if (!queryInit) {
            queryInit = true;
            // Using the $q promise library we use 'then()' to handle
            // What happens after the async call is returned
            // The first function parameter is the success/resolve callback
            // The second function parameter is the error/reject callback
            mService.query().then(function (successResults) {
                // Tell all of the controllers that the data has changed
                $rootScope.$broadcast('messages.update');
            }, function (errorResults) {
                console.error(errorResults);
            });
        }
    };

    // Used to force an update from the controller if needed.
    mService.query = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('path/to/file.php')
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // assign the returned values appropriately
            mService.messages = data;
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
            deferred.resolve(data);
        })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
            deferred.reject(data);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    mService.getCount = function () {
        return mService.messages.length;
    };

    mService.all = function () {
        return mService.messages;
    };

    // Initialize the messages
    // so we don't need to get the messages in each controller
    getMessages();

    return mService;
}]);
```

In your html, on your first controller setup an init function (`ng-init="init()"`) that instantiates the factory:

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="HeaderCtrl" class="header" ng-init="init()">
        Messages Count: {{ messageCount }}
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="DashboardCtrl" class="dashboard">
        <ul ng-repeat="message in messages">
            <li>{{ message }}</li>
        </ul>
        <button ng-click="getMessages()">Check for new messages.</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in your controllers you just have the `$rootScope.$on('messages.update' fn)` and you can call manually by calling the services `query()` function which returns the promise:

```javascript
myApp.controller('HeaderCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$rootScope',
    'messagesService',

function ($scope, $rootScope, messagesService) {
    $rootScope.$on('messages.update', function () {
        $scope.messageCount = messagesService.getCount();
    });

    // Manual call, if needed
    $scope.getMessageCount = function () {
        messagesService.query().then(function (successCallback) {
            $scope.messageCount = messagesService.getCount();
        });
    };
}]);

myApp.controller('DashboardCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$rootScope',
    'messagesService',

function ($scope, $rootScope, messagesService) {
    $rootScope.$on('messages.update', function () {
        $scope.messages = messagesService.all();
    });

    // Manual call, if needed
    $scope.getMessages = function () {
        messagesService.query().then(function (successCallback) {
            $scope.messages = messagesService.all();
            $rootScope.$broadcast('messages.update');
        });
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks Asok! I really like how you simplified the factory. How would you change this if you didn't have a guarantee that the header was included? Would there still be an `init`? What if it wasn't dashboard and header but dashboard and dashboard 2, where the inclusion of those is arbitrary or random?

Comment: The init function can be on every controller, `ng-init` just declares what you want to call on controller initialization. If the init function is added to every controller than your `getMessages()` function within the factory can be changed to only query if `mService.messages.length < 1` or `!mService.messages.length` you could also add a function that queries the database whether a query has been completed or not for those instances were you need to update the data.

Comment: I was wrong, using the messages length will not work since all queries will more than likely be called before the data is returned. So I have added an init boolean to the factory and before running the asynchronous call make sure to change the value to true. I also added a init function with `getMessages` in both controllers and split out the query into a separate function that can be called by itself to force an update. [Here is my updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P7KpT/6/). Let me know if you would like me to update my answer to reflect.

Comment: I see what you're doing. I like those changes and I see it only queries once. Is there a way to roll this logic into the factory itself so I can avoid the code duplication on each controller? I'll play around with your example. Thanks!

Comment: I updated your fiddle. I moved the getMessages call into the factory and removed the inits(). It seems to have the same functionality. Do you see any problems with this? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dihedral/P7KpT/7/)

Comment: Not at all, I was making those same changes when I got interrupted. Looks good! Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can set `cache:true` on a `$http` request. There are numerous ways to data bind within angular without needing to use the $broadcast approach you are using. Also note, $broadcast from a scope will be receievd by all descendent scopes, so no need to inject $rootSCope just for that purpose, can listen on $scope.

Here's one approach that controllers use promise of $http to retrieve data. I used a button click to retrive data for `DashControl` so can see that request does get cached

```
myApp.factory('messagesService',function($http) {  

    return{
      query:function query(callback) {
          /* return promise of the request*/
          return $http.get('messages.json',{ cache:true}).then(function(res){
              /* resolve what data to return, can set additional properties of the service here if desired*/
              return res.data
          }).then(callback);         
      }
    }       
});

myApp.controller('HeaderCtrl',function($scope, messagesService) {

     messagesService.query(function(messages){
       $scope.messagesCount = messages.length;
     });

});

myApp.controller('DashboardCtrl', function($scope, messagesService) {

  /* use button click to load same data, note in console no http request made*/
  $scope.getMessages=function(){
      messagesService.query(function(messages){
       $scope.messages = messages;
     })
   }

});
```

Essentially in this scenario, whatever controller calls the factory service first will generate the data cache

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/mtCpZTmsOyjWXvVNUADx?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the cache advice. That's something I hadn't thought of. I'm planning to use Restangular for backend communications. I'll see if that has caching, or access to caching from $http.

Comment: most definitely...shoudl ahve mentioned restangular to begin with.....learn to work with promises. Angular has lot of promise handling under the hood

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like that:

```
myApp.factory('messagesService', function() {
        var expose = {
            messages: []
        };

        expose.query = function () {
            // Would actually hit the database asyncronously
            expose.messages = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
            console.log('query');
        };

        // Initialization
        expose.query();

        return expose;
    }
);
```

And in your controllers:

$scope.messagesCount = messagesService.messages.length;

Answer (score 0):

Model with broadcasting and pre-hitting database looks heavy for me.

So here is code, that can be embedded in service:

```
var sv = this;
var deferred = sv.$q.defer();
if (sv._running) { 
    return sv._running;
}
sv._running = deferred;
```

It based on reusing promise. To make it query database once - just don't set `sv._running` to false and it will always return first obtained result.